# Is there anyway to use the clarity icons without the custom-elements polyfill?

Tags: vmware-clarity

All of the CSS in the @clr/icons and @clr/ui match on the element name clr-icon.

Is there anyway to use the icons without using the custom element web component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the icons as described in the documentation you need the poly fill. However the svg files for each of the icons is available in the source code If you wanted to craft a non custom-element solution.

The SVG’s are also available to download directly from the icons documentation page.

Just for my curiosity, can you elaborate on why custom-elements don’t work for you?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the custom element to work with Vue components.  I can easily create an icon view component and use the SVG from the typescript library, but then I'm missing out on all of the styling done in CSS that match against clr-icon.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction on stackblitz or something to show?

Comment: I am not a vue expert but I quickly spun up a demo vue project with their cli and added the icon assets and custom-element poly fills in the index (linking from unpkg.com) and icons works. I'm sure there is a better way to add polyfills to a vue project but this shows that Clarity Icons will work with vue: https://github.com/hippee-lee/vue-clarity-icons

Comment: See here for the exact change: https://github.com/hippee-lee/vue-clarity-icons/blob/master/public/index.html#L10